# Struts2JQuery JS Tree generation & binding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2-json-plugin

How to implement Struts2Jquery js tree to generate a tree and bind a function to the nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjt" uri="/struts-jquery-tree-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<sj:head />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/jquery.contextmenu.r2.packed.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.tree.struts2-3.2.1"
                + jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix + ".js");
            //Binding a function to the click of the nodes
            $.subscribe('clickFunction', function(event,element) {
                var key = $(".jstree-clicked").parent().attr("key");
                foo(key);
            });
            refreshTree(id);
        });
        function foo(key) {
            alert(key);
        }

        // This function is used to draw the tree and can also be called to refresh the tree.
        function refreshTree(id) {
            var options_jsonTree = {};
            options_jsonTree.treetheme = "default";
            options_jsonTree.url = "StrutsAction.action?id=" + id;
            options_jsonTree.onclick = "clickFunction";
            options_jsonTree.plugins = "contextmenu";
            options_jsonTree.jqueryaction = "tree";
            options_jsonTree.id = "jsonTree";
            jQuery.struts2_jquery_tree.bind(jQuery('#jsonTree'),options_jsonTree);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jsonTree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```